# How to deploy same functionality, with different data source with symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, multiple-instances

I have a software product that i would like to deploy an arbitrary number of times, with the same functionality, but with different data sources. I would also like to be able to instantiate each automatically, by running a script.

I am using symfony2, and am thinking about using environments. Would this work? Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It is definetly possible and there are many ways you can do it. It all depends how are you getting you data.

For instance if you are simply using files you can user parameters to specify the location of the file.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html